# prove if a|b and b|a then $a = \pm b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Fairly basic I guess.

Attempt:

$a\neq\pm b \Rightarrow a\nmid b \vee b \nmid a$

let $a = \pm b + d, d\in \mathrm{Z} \wedge d\neq 0$

then $a\mid b \Rightarrow b\nmid a$ and $b\mid a \Rightarrow a\nmid b$

Comment: I don't think the attempt makes much sense. How do you translate the condition $a|b$ into algebra?

Comment: It is proof by contraposition.  'a|b' means 'a divides b.'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$, then $|a|=|b|$ , $a, b$ are integers.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512560/prove-if-a-mid-b-and-b-mid-a-then-a-b-a-b-are-integers)

Comment: But not really a duplicate, since OP has an explicit, though incorrect argument.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: 'OP'=?  How is my argument incorrect?

Comment: The last line just *asserts* the result is true, does not explicitly use the fact that $d\ne 0$. OP is original post, or original poster.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: It kind of uses it as 'then' is like an implication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$b|a \rightarrow a = kb$, and

$a|b \rightarrow b = na$. Thus:

$a = k(na) = kna$, and assume $a \neq 0$, so: $nk = 1$. Thus:

either $n = k = 1$ or $n = k = -1$ which means $a = b$ or $a = - b$

Comment: I started out trying to solve it like that and figured that's the best way.  Might want to add that if a is 0 , 0 does not divide anything I don't think so proof still holds.

Comment: @user2008730 If $a=0$, then from $b=na$ you get $b=0$. In other words, $0$ divides only $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$a|b$ so $b=ak$ for some integer $k$. Similarly, $b|a$ implies $a=bl$ for some integer $l$. Putting these together you get $b=ak=(bl)k=bkl$, which implies $1=kl$. Which integers can $k$ and $l$ be such that their product is $1$?

Answer (score 1):

(1) If $u$ divides $v$, then $|u|$ divides $|v|$.

(2) If $u$ divides $v$, with $u>0$ and $v>0$, then $u\le v$.

Suppose $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $a$.

By (1), we have $|a|$ divides $|b|$ and $|b|$ divides $|a|$.

By (2), we have $|a| \le |b| \le |a|$, which implies $|a|=|b|$. This means that $a=\pm b$.

Comment: Here "divides" is more natural than "less-than" - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $b = qa$ for some integer $q \neq 0$ and $a = q'b$ for some integer $q' \neq 0,$ we have
$$b = qq'b,$$
so that 
$$1 = qq',$$
whence
$$q, q' = 1\ or\ q, q'= -1.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ |a|\,\overset{\underset{}{\large a\,\mid\, b}}=\gcd(a,b)\overset{\underset{}{\large b\,\mid\, a}}=|b|$